# Prove combinatorics equality?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs, multinomial-theorem

Assume $j$ is fixed, prove the following:
$$\sum_{i}\binom{n}{i, j, n-i-j} = 2^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}$$
So the left hand side reminds me the multinomial theorem and we can think of a long sequence word that made with $3$ types of letter. The number of first type is $i$, second is $j$ and third is $n - i - j.$
But I'm not sure how the summation and $j$ is fixed matters here and to made the LHS equal to RHS by some tricks.

Any help would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're most of the way there. Let's count the number of words of length $n$ in the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$, with $a$ occurring $j$ times. One way to do this is to first fix the $a$'s, which contributes a factor of $\binom{n}{j}$, and all remaining characters can be either $b$ or $c$, contributing a factor of $2^{n-j}$, giving us the right hand side.

Another way to count this is to sum over all possible number of $b$'s that occur. If $b$ occurs $i$ times, there are $\binom{n}{i,j,n-i-j}$ such strings, and summing over all $i$, we have the left hand side.

Comment: nice answer....

Comment: But by this we get n!/(n-i-j)!(i+j)! Won't it be n!/(n-i-j)!(i)!(j!) As  I A's  and j B's there by mutinomial theorem?

Answer (score 1):

For an algebriac proof: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{i,j,n-i-j} =  \binom{n}{j} \binom{n-j}{i}
\end{eqnarray*}
and use the binomial theorem.

For a combinatorial proof: The RHS counts words of length $n$ on the alphabet $\{0,1,2 \}$ with exactly $j$ $0$'s.

The LHS counts words with $j$ $0$'s and $i$ $1$'s ... and $i$ varies from $0$ to $n-j$.